# Loop troubles with string insertions

Tags: java

So my last question got derailed but I got the problem solved (compile errors, lots of them). Now I'm left with at least one logic error, maybe two. The purpose of the program is to "encrypt" strings by reversing them and adding a certain number of random letters between each 'real' character, dependent on the 'difficulty' value. [Here](http://pastebin.com/i2V51TJm) is the entirety of the code.

Here are the sections I think are causing me problems, more specifically I'm pretty sure it has to do with my `x = x + diff`statement, but I don't know how else I would move the "cursor".
--Snip from Decryptor.java--

```
/**
decryptString decrypts the code based on using the difficulty as the increment.
@param code The encrypted string
@return decrypted The decrypted string
*/
    public String decryptString(String code)
    {
        int length = code.length();
        int x = 0; //to 1
        encryptedStr = code;

        String codeRev = new StringBuilder(code).reverse().toString();

        StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();

         for (int pos = 0; pos <= length; pos++)
         {
            if (x < length) //removed <=
            {
                decrypted.append(codeRev.charAt(x));
            }               
            x = x + diff;
         }
         decryptedStr = decrypted.toString();
         return(decrypted).toString();
    }
```

--Snip from Encryptor.java--

```
/** 
    encryptString encrypts the string, as well as stores the original for later use
    @param str The string to be encrypted
    @return encrypted The encrypted string
    */
    public String encryptString(String str)
    {
        int length = str.length();
        origStr = str;
        int x = 0; //to 0
        StringBuilder codeRev = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();

         for (int pos = 0; pos <= length; pos++)
         {
            if (x < length + diff) //removed 
            {
                codeRev.insert(x, randomLetter());
            }               
            x = x + diff;
         }
         encryptedStr = codeRev.toString();
         return(codeRev).toString();

    }
```

If anyone could help me modify the loops to function as they are supposed to, it would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying this thing off and on all day.

This is an example of what it should do:

for diff = 0
Legocats -> stacogeL -> Legocats

for diff = 1
Legocats -> s_t_a_c_o_g_e_L -> Legocats
"_" representing a random letter.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't verified your code but it shouldn't be too difficult.

For decryption, assume we have a string

```
A_B_C_D  (difficulty = 1),
```

what you can do is set the cursor to the end (and append to the result):

```
A_B_C_D
      ^
```

For each iteration, move back `diff + 1` elements, e.g. move back 2 in this case

```
A_B_C_D
    ^
```

until you passed index 0.
Here is the psuedo code

```
String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    int i = encryptedString.length() - 1;
    String result = "" ;  // use a String builder in real life of course

    for (int i = encryptedString.length() - 1   // last index
            ; i >= 0
            ; i -= (diff + 1) ) {
        result += encryptedString[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is just this simple.  And this avoid extra steps to do reverse (and hence, save unnecessary memory waste) without losing readability.

Encryption is even easier:

```
String encrypt (String input) {
    String result;
    for (int i = input.length() - 1
            ; i >= 0
            ; --i) {
        result += input[i];
        if (i > 0) {
            append "diff" number of random character to result
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Although I am suggesting a new approach, I personally think OP should try improve his own debugging technique.  I think the bug he is facing now can be easily identified by using a debugger, or even by adding some debug println statements.  E.g. for each loop, print out `x` and the corresponding character.  It should have already give a big hint on what goes wrong.

Comment: I've had the decryption work before, it was a question on its own at one point. The problem I'm having here is incorporating the diff variable, as well as getting the encryption method to actually work, as is neither of them work because one is dependent on the other. Thank you for your suggestion though, I will look into it tomorrow when I'm done my day classes.

Comment: In my pseudo code it should have already shown clearly how you can use that diff value.  Will add pseudo code for encrypt too if you want.  I usually only giving out idea by psuedo code instead of real code as transforming such idea to real code should be trivial and should be the responsibility of questioner

Comment: Okay, I'm still not gettin it. The strings are doin weird things, the original string can bee seen, and then a flipped and encrypted... in the same string. I have no idea what is going on here anymore. EX: 
`Encrypting String: Agent: James Bond ...
Encrypted as: Agent: James BonddtpnhqoaqBdh prsusekxmgnawwJkn la:shtqentnebpgayA
Decrypting String: Agent: James BonddtpnhqoaqBdh prsusekxmgnawwJkn la:shtqentnebpgayA 
Decrypted as: Agent: James BonddtpnhqoaqBdh prsusekxmgnawwJkn la:shtqentnebpgayAAgent: James Bondosa:e`

Comment: I'm pretty sure my problem lies in either the append or the loop containing, I've confirmed that the randomLetter() works as desired, so the append must be at fault, either it's positioning or what I don't know. I've updated the pastebin with my latest code. [link](http://pastebin.com/i2V51TJm)

Comment: Okay... redefined the string builder in encryptor to initialize with a blank string and that seems to have solved one problem. Now to pore over decryptor again.

EDIT: Did the same for De and it works, thank you for inspiring my success. :)

Comment: initialize with blank string? I think you are doing something wrong.... I don't see any place in my pseudo code that requires you to explicitly initialize the StringBuilder.  Don't tell me you are returning the StringBuilder (instead of returning the result String by `sb.toString()`)

Comment: I had `Stringbuilder result = new Stringbuilder(input)`, which is why the text was cloning itself in weird ways. I removed `input` from the parentheses and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that should be a stricter `pos < length - 1` :

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < length - 1; pos++)
```

Also this seems to be better from what I understand :

```
codeRev.insert(pos * 2 + 1, randomLetter());
```

And remove x. Just skip the for `if (diff == 0)`

Comment: Opposed to the method above, yours does not cause a runtime error, and seems to be on the right track as well, but it still isn't decrypting very nicely. It seems as though the characters are inserted too far along and then take out from the wrong places as a consequence of that.

Comment: The method above works except for diff = 0. You have to add the IF to skip the WHILE as well, like `WHILE (diff > 0 && x < codeRev.length())`

Answer (score 1):

You had a few mistakes in the algorithm.
First of all, you don't want to iterate over `length`, because the length of the string is changing.
Solution: This works for me for

```
   public static String decryptString(String code)
{
    int length = code.length();
    int x = 0; 

    String codeRev = code;

    StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();

    while(x < codeRev.length())
    {
        for(int i = x; i< x + diff && i < codeRev.length();i++)
           decrypted.append(codeRev.charAt(i));

        x += diff + 1;
    }
    decrypted = decrypted.reverse();
    return(decrypted).toString();
}
public static String encryptString(String str)
{
    int length = str.length();
    String origStr = str;
    int x = diff;
    StringBuilder codeRev = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();

    while (x < codeRev.length())
    {
        codeRev.insert(x, " ");
        x += diff + 1;
    }
    return(codeRev).toString();

}
```

Comment: So, it certainly makes sense the way you've restructured it, but I cannot get the program to run correctly anymore. Here is the run-time error I get:

Comment: ==============================
Simulating difficulty level 0:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.insert(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1187)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(StringBuilder.java:338)
 at Encryptor.encryptString(Encryptor.java:32)
 at Simulator.main(Simulator.java:28)

Comment: try to debug and find the problem